# Extend vg-ubuntu--lv after adding space in vSphere

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, resize

I did setup a new Ubuntu Server 22.04.03 on my ESXi enviroment. First i created the VM with 200GB of harddisk space but later increased it via vSphere to 230 GB. I changed the partition size accordingly but i think i made a mistake as i can't resize my vg-ubuntu--lv partition.

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                      FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT        LABEL
loop0                     squashfs     63,4M /snap/core20/1974
loop1                     squashfs    111,9M /snap/lxd/24322
loop2                     squashfs     63,5M /snap/core20/2015
loop3                     squashfs     53,3M /snap/snapd/19457
loop4                     squashfs     40,9M /snap/snapd/20290
sda                                     230G
├─sda1                                    1M
├─sda2                    ext4            2G /boot
└─sda3                    LVM2_member   228G
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4          198G /
```

As you can see, my sda3 partition is about 228G und my vg-ubuntu--lv only 198G. What do I have to do, to increase the partition correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend your physical volume, your volume group, your logical volume and your filesystem.

1. First backup any data that you cannot afford to lose.
2. Then establish what you have got with the `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` commands. This will also help to identify the correct names to use.
3. Extend the physical volume with `pvresize /dev/sda3`. You can check this worked with `pvdisplay`
4. Extend the volume group with `vgextend <VG_Name> /dev/sda3`  (Replace <VG_Name> with your actual VG name as per the output of vgdisplay . You can check this worked with `vgdisplay`
5. Extend the logical volume with `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/<VG_Name>/<LV_Name>` using the names you identified earlier. You can check this worked with `lvdisplay`
6. Extend the filesystem with `resize2fs /dev/<VG_Name>/<LV_Name>` . You can check this worked with `df -h`

Don’t be confused by the <> brackets. Your commands should not include them. eg `resize2fs /dev/name/name1`

Good luck

Comment: Thank you! This was everything i needed (except step 4, i got an error message).

Comment: What happened at step 4? Did you succeed overall?